# Pointers and dictionary : copied or stored?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, memory, nsdictionary

It seems that the object stored in a dictionary is a copy of the original object !
So strange !!

In the following code,

```
myData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myEntries, preambule, nil]
            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myEntries", @"preambule", nil]];

NSMutableArray * myEntriesDico = [myData objectForKey:@"myEntries"] ;
NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!! Address of myEntries (in the le dict) : %p", &myEntriesDico);
NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!! Address of myEntries : %p", &myEntries);
```

I got two different addresses !

Anyone knows what's happening ?

Comment: It is always DeepCopy.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I'm not sure what you're referring to as "it," but AFAIK Cocoa has no facilities for deep copying.

Comment: Am I saying vice-versa... Deep means byValue, shallow means byRef... :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - for a reference type (e.g. `NSObject *`) then (a) assignment copies the value (the reference) (b) shallow copy creates a new object of the type referenced and assigns the values of the source object's instance variables to those of the new object (c) deep copy performs (b) recursively - if any of the source objects instance variables are of reference type then new objects for those are created. Unless otherwise stated Obj-C collections just do an assignment (usually with retain), they do not shallow or deep copy objects.

Comment: @CRD: I am stuck. I have an dictionary added a string= @"A".  later i updated the string=@"B". the dictionary does not reflect @"B", it still has @"A".

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : just a guess -> try with `NSMutableString` ? (and the method `setString` ? I guess it is a problem of adresses : when you update the string, it changes the adress of the objet (what you want is, I guess : keep the same adress but change only the value).

@CRD : this problem is only for strings ?

Comment: mut and immu tried with both

Comment: Tried to use the method `setString` of `NSMutableString` ? Ie : `[myMutableString setString:@"myNewValue"]` ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, @Colas: When you execute `myData[@"someKey"] = someVar;` (or `[myData setObject:someVar forKey:@"someKey"]` then the *value* (of some reference type) that is stored in the variable `someVar` is stored in the dict. A later assignment to `someVar`, e.g. `someVar = somethingElse;` has no effect on `myData`. If what you have stored in `someVar` is a reference to a mutable object, say an instance of `NSMutableString`, then changes to that mutable object are reflected in the dict - the contents of the dict **does not change**, just what is found by following the reference stored in it.

Comment: So both keys+objects are copied(new copy) in dictionary? Without using KVO is it possible to update the dictionary in sync with the update of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've simply printed the wrong thing. `myEntriesDico` and `myEntries` are two *distinct* variables whose *values* are the same - and those values are references.

When you pass `&myEntries` to `NSLog` you are passing a reference to the `myEntries` variable and not the value within it, same for `myEntriesDico`.

Drop the two `&`'s, that will pass the values, which are references, and `%p` will format them correctly - and the two outputs should be the same.